# Как на Unity програмно создать группу переключателей (ToggleGroup)?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Прошу помощи с примером для Unity програмного создания группы переключателей. И обработки событий переключения в ней.
Ничего по данной теме не "гуглится", только создание через редактор, а уже далее программная работа с ней.
Обычный переключатель создается, например, через GUILayout.Toggle(...). А как создать группу, чтобы значение устанавливалось только для одного?

Comment: Возможно, это то, что вам нужно: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763298/unity-multiple-toggle-buttons-reversing

Comment: ...Вкратце там в одном из ответов предлагают хранить в ToggleButton ссылки на остальные ToggleButton и при включении одного, отключать другие. Если ToggleButton много, то, возможно, стоит создать скрипт ToggleButtonGroup,  в котором хранить список ссылкок на всеToggleButton'ы группы, и в методе OnToggleButtonChecked(int index) устанавлить все, ToggleButton, кроме index, на false.

Comment: Спасибо, я думал о таком решении - создать несколько переключателей и обрабатывать их как группу самостоятельно. Просто, думал, что если я сделаю так, а потом окажется, что есть уже готовый механизм для этого, будет несколько стыдно.

Comment: Погодите-ка, если вам нужно готовое решение, то чем не угодил [Toggle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2018.4/Manual/script-Toggle.html) и [ToggleGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2018.4/Manual/script-ToggleGroup.html)

Comment: Вам нужно повесить Toggle на все ваши ToggleButton. Все их засунуть в один объект-родитель (хотя это не обязательно), после чего на родителя повесить ToggleGroup. В Toggle у всех ToggleButton указать в инспекторе параметр Group на объект-родитель. Теперь все ToggleButton'ы, прикрепленные к одному и тому же ToggleGroup будут объединены в одну группу

Comment: Спасибо вам, что пытаетесь помочь. Но, видимо, вы не внимательно читали мой вопрос. Я писал: как это сделать программно, через скрипты, а не используя редактор Unity? Об этом есть куча информации, но нет информации о программном создании группы переключателей. Также есть, например информация, как программно создать различные простые "контролы", но вот о чем-то чуть более сложном как группа переключателей я информации не нашел - https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/gui-Controls.html. Если все же это я вас неправильно понял, прошу набросать небольшой пример-шаблон, чтобы можно было понять сам метод.

Comment: В документации к Unity есть упоминания об такой группе. У класса Toggle есть свойство group: "Group the toggle belongs to" - https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.1/ScriptReference/UI.Toggle.html. Или есть сам класс ToggleGroup - https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.2/ScriptReference/UI.ToggleGroup.html. Т.е. я могу создавать такие объекты на основе классов, но не могу понять, как сделать их отображение как "контролов". Или я могу создавать отображение этих "контролов" с помощью вызова методов классов GUI или GUILayout (ссылка выше), но там я не нашел метода для создания группы переключателей.

Comment: Поэтому и просил помощи с примером создания, отображения и обработки событий с помощью "Scripting API". И без использования редактора вообще. Пока вижу только возможность создания отдельных Toggle и работой с ними как с группой. И не важно в данном случае, как это реализовать: инкапсуляцией в собственном классе или просто в отдельном методе обработчика события, вроде Update, FixedUpdate и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Введение: Пока что у меня в голове нет определенной картины того, что вам нужно, однако после ваших последних трех комментариев, думаю лучше дать ответ.

---

Итак, вам нужно **программно** создать ToggleGroup с ToggleButton'ами (далее переключатель). Для меня данная задача выглядит следующим образом: из скрипта создать на сцене объект с компонентом ToggleGroup, в котором будут несколько переключателей, объединенных в одну группу.

Предлагаю следующий скрипт:

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject TogglePrefab; // Префаб переключателя

public void CreateToggles () { // Метод для создания группы с переключателями
    ToggleGroup Group = new GameObject().AddComponent<ToggleGroup>(); // Создаем объект с ToggleGroup 
    for (int i = 0; i < [кол-во переключателей]; i++) {
      GameObject newToggleButton = Instantiate(TogglePrefab, [позиция],  Quaternion.identity); // Создаем новый переключатель
      newToggleButton.GetComponent<Toggle>().Group = Group; // Кладем его в группу
    }
}
```

Получаем метод, который при вызове создает группы переключателей. Естественно, в параметрах можно указать, например, кол-во переключателей и т.д.

Префаб переключателя создается заранее, указывается скрипту в инспекторе, а текст переключателя и картинку (если нужно) вы можете уже из кода заменить, например, текст на переключателе через `transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>() = "текст"`. 
*По-моему текст переключателя находится в переключателе (вмсысле, переключатель - родитель), поэтому через GetChild(0) получаем первого дочернего объекта переключателя и меняем тот текст.*

---

Заключение: Если я все-таки не понял вашу идею, распишите ее подробнее. Если все верно, напишите или примите ответ - удалю введение и заключение.

Comment: @Corhal Если мой ответ вам помог, то примите его, если у вас есть вопросы, то задавайте их в комментариях к ответу. Оставлять ответ без внимания как-то не очень красиво

Comment: Что ж, ладно...